# Streaming tab is not showing for structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-ui

I am using structured streaming for reading csvs and writing to kafka. The streaming tab is not showing in Spark UI (not using streaming context).

```
val userSchema = new StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")
val csvDF = spark
  .readStream
  .option("sep", ";")
  .schema(userSchema)      // Specify schema of the csv files
  .csv("/path/to/directory")
```

How can I get streaming metrics in the UI?

Comment: Streaming tab is for Spark Streaming, not Structured Streaming. What metrics are you looking for? Did you look under the SQL tab?

Comment: How can i get  visualization in ui for structured streaming something like streaming tab ?

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/11424/streaming-tab-is-not-available-on-spark-ui-for-str.html

You'll have to implement a listener like @gaston has suggested, and push those events to a monitoring service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see some metrics (in console), you need to add a listener

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener {
  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = logger.debug(s"QueryStarted [id = ${event.id}, name = ${event.name}, runId = ${event.runId}]")

  override def onQueryProgress(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent): Unit = logger.warn(s"QueryProgress ${event.progress}")

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = logger.debug(s"QueryTerminated [id = ${event.id}, runId = ${event.runId}, error = ${event.exception}]")
})
```

`QueryProgressEvent`, displays info about offset, watermarks, source, sinks,etc.

This video can help you : [Monitoring Structured Streaming Applications](https://databricks.com/session/monitoring-structured-streaming-applications-using-web-ui)

Comment: i can see metrics in console. how can i add them to UI ?

Comment: The question does ask about the streaming tab specifically, not about console metrics.